# Why am I having problems with Laravel Websockets package?

Tags: laravel

I have found out about the Laravel WebSockets package and tested it on localhost, and it works fine. However, after deploying, I have the following problems.

Depending on whether these values are uncommented or not in the .env file, I cannot connect to WebSocket URL via Laravel echo, but can via tinker. if I comment these out, I cannot connect via tinker, but can via echo.

```php
'ssl' => [
    /*
     * Path to local certificate file on the filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
     * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
     * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
     * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
     */
    'local_cert' => env('WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),

    /*
     * Path to local private key file on the filesystem in case of separate files for
     * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
     */
    'local_pk' => env('WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),
],
```

My `broadcasting.php`:

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'encrypted' => true,
        'useTLS' => true,
        'host' => "127.0.0.1",
        'port' => '6001',
        'scheme' => "https",
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: Do you using SSL from [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/zh-cn/)?

Comment: yes i do why does that matter

Comment: Does this help? Worked for me.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964481/2562428](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964481/2562428)

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me on both localhost-dev and online-prod

**config/broadcasting.php**

```php
<?php
$ssl_pusher_config = [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'encrypted' => true,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => 'https',
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        ]
    ]
];

$not_ssl_pusher_config = [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'encrypted' => true,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => 'http'
    ]
];

return [
    ...
    'connections' => [
         // do not use SSL in localhost
        'pusher' => env('APP_ENV') === 'local' ? $not_ssl_pusher_config : $ssl_pusher_config,
        ...
    ],
];
```

**config/websockets.php**

```php
'ssl' => [
     'local_cert' => env('WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),
     'local_pk' => env('WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),
     'passphrase' => env('WEBSOCKETS_PASSPHRASE', null),
     'verify_peer' => false,
 ],
```

**.env**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
...
PUSHER_APP_ID=appid
PUSHER_APP_KEY=websocketkey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=secret
...
WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
```

---

In your front-end

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
let echor = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    // I am using JWT for auth, if you are using session, please ignore this
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer abcdefgh1234`
        }
    }
});
export default echor;
```

Comment: my wsHost is on a different subdomain than my app, so i also cannot use wssPort

Comment: when i comment out both WEBSOCKETS_SSL env vars, my client can connect, but not through tinker