# Websockets not working: Failed without error

Tags: laravel-8, pusher-js, laravel-websockets

I setup a websocket server in a laravel 8 project that is accessible from the internet. I then installed the laravel-websockets package 1.12 together with the pusherphpserver package 5.0.

I have created an account on the Pusher's API website and added the credentials correctly in the .env file. The server is running correctly:

```
# php artisan websockets:serve
Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...
```

I have also forwarded the port 6001 correctly in the router.

However, when clicking on connect on the websockets webpage on my server I receive this:

```
pusher.min.js:8 WebSocket connection to 'wss://mywebpage.com:6001/app/dfab1c1740a1ce5b1688?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed:
```

No other error is present and the connection cannot be established.

This is the websockets.php config file:

```
<?php

use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Dashboard\Http\Middleware\Authorize;

return [

    /*
     * Set a custom dashboard configuration
     */
    'dashboard' => [
        'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
    ],

    /*
     * This package comes with multi tenancy out of the box. Here you can
     * configure the different apps that can use the webSockets server.
     *
     * Optionally you specify capacity so you can limit the maximum
     * concurrent connections for a specific app.
     *
     * Optionally you can disable client events so clients cannot send
     * messages to each other via the webSockets.
     */
    'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],

    /*
     * This class is responsible for finding the apps. The default provider
     * will use the apps defined in this config file.
     *
     * You can create a custom provider by implementing the
     * `AppProvider` interface.
     */
    'app_provider' => BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Apps\ConfigAppProvider::class,

    /*
     * This array contains the hosts of which you want to allow incoming requests.
     * Leave this empty if you want to accept requests from all hosts.
     */
    'allowed_origins' => [
        //
    ],

    /*
     * The maximum request size in kilobytes that is allowed for an incoming WebSocket request.
     */
    'max_request_size_in_kb' => 250,

    /*
     * This path will be used to register the necessary routes for the package.
     */
    'path' => 'laravel-websockets',

    /*
     * Dashboard Routes Middleware
     *
     * These middleware will be assigned to every dashboard route, giving you
     * the chance to add your own middleware to this list or change any of
     * the existing middleware. Or, you can simply stick with this list.
     */
    'middleware' => [
        'web',
        Authorize::class,
    ],

    'statistics' => [
        /*
         * This model will be used to store the statistics of the WebSocketsServer.
         * The only requirement is that the model should extend
         * `WebSocketsStatisticsEntry` provided by this package.
         */
        'model' => \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Statistics\Models\WebSocketsStatisticsEntry::class,

        /**
         * The Statistics Logger will, by default, handle the incoming statistics, store them
         * and then release them into the database on each interval defined below.
         */
        'logger' => BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Statistics\Logger\HttpStatisticsLogger::class,

        /*
         * Here you can specify the interval in seconds at which statistics should be logged.
         */
        'interval_in_seconds' => 60,

        /*
         * When the clean-command is executed, all recorded statistics older than
         * the number of days specified here will be deleted.
         */
        'delete_statistics_older_than_days' => 60,

        /*
         * Use an DNS resolver to make the requests to the statistics logger
         * default is to resolve everything to 127.0.0.1.
         */
        'perform_dns_lookup' => false,
    ],

    /*
     * Define the optional SSL context for your WebSocket connections.
     * You can see all available options at: http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php
     */
    'ssl' => [
        /*
         * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
         * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
         * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
         * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
         */
        'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),

        /*
         * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for
         * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
         */
        'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),

        /*
         * Passphrase for your local_cert file.
         */
        'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),

        'verify_peer' => false,
    ],

    /*
     * Channel Manager
     * This class handles how channel persistence is handled.
     * By default, persistence is stored in an array by the running webserver.
     * The only requirement is that the class should implement
     * `ChannelManager` interface provided by this package.
     */
    'channel_manager' => \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\Channels\ChannelManagers\ArrayChannelManager::class,
];
```

And this is the broadcasting.php config file:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
            ],
        ],

        'ably' => [
            'driver' => 'ably',
            'key' => env('ABLY_KEY'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the website is only using https and I hadn't configured the SSL certificates correctly inside websockets.php config file.

Comment: Hi I'm also facing the same issue can you tell me what to set up SSL in config file

Comment: @matheenulla Please create a new question, post your configs there and tag me so we can talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem but have finally resolved it. Here's what worked for me. AWS EC2 + Ubuntu + [Laravel-Websockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction) + Apache2 + SSL (Let's Encrypt - same cert as Apache2 is using). The undefined error for me was due to Laravel-Websockets not being able to open the SSL certificates (permissions issue), and also setting the Pusher Host to 127.0.0.1 (per a lot of tutorials) meant the SSL certificate was invalid (needed to be a FQDN). My laravel installation is in /var/www/laravel.

I didn't have any luck getting it to work on HTTP initially (my website forces HTTPS), and now that it's working on HTTPS I don't want to break anything trying to go back to HTTP.

Hope this helps someone!

Note: The /laravel-websockets dashboard only works in **local**, not **production**. Laravel Telescope also helped me to see that the Events were being broadcast correctly so I recommend installing that.

1. Copy SSL certificates **/etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain]/fullchain.pem** and **privkey.pem** to **/var/www/laravel/ssl** and **chown** the copied files to **www-data**.
2. Make sure **PUSHER_APP_HOST** matches your website's domain, otherwise your SSL certificate will be invalid, leading to the undefined error. Here is my **.env** file:

   PUSHER_APP_HOST=**make this the same as APP_DOMAIN so SSL cert is valid**

   PUSHER_APP_PORT=6001

   PUSHER_APP_ID=12345

   PUSHER_APP_KEY=12345

   PUSHER_APP_SECRET=12345

   PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

   LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT="/var/www/laravel/ssl/fullchain.pem"

   LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK="/var/www/laravel/ssl/privkey.pem"
3. Here is my **config/broadcasting.php** file:

   'connections' => [

   ```
    'pusher' => [

        'driver' => 'pusher',

        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),

        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),

        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),

        'options' => [

            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),

            'encrypted' => true,

            'host' => env('PUSHER_APP_HOST'),

            'port' => env('PUSHER_APP_PORT'),

            'scheme' => 'https',

            'curl_options' => [

                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,

                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,

            ],

        ],

    ],

    ...
   ```

   ]
4. Here is my **config/websockets.php** file:

   'apps' => [

   ```
    [

        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),

        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),

        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),

        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),

        'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),

        'capacity' => null,

        'enable_client_messages' => false,

        'enable_statistics' => true,

    ],
   ```

   ],

   'ssl' => [

   ```
    'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),

    'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),

    'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),

    'verify_peer' => false,

    'verify_peer_name' => false,

    'allow_self_signed' => true,
   ```

   ],
5. Make sure you run the Supervisor task as **www-data** (and never root). Here is the contents of my **/etc/supervisor/conf.d/websockets.conf** file:

   [program:websockets]

   command=/usr/bin/php /var/www/laravel/artisan websockets:serve

   numprocs=1

   autostart=true

   autorestart=true

   user=www-data

Answer (score 0):

ok in my case i first figured out that i was using the https but has not installed the ssl certificate i fixed it and coverted the https to http in the local environment it started working and after a while a make a new event and faced the same issue this time the issue was i gave the name of channel 'Hrm Notification' so i fixed it and converted to "Notification" i mean no space is allowed in the channel name hope this works for you also.