# Unable to configure laravel websocket with laravel 9

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-websockets

Is there any issue with laravel 9 im not getting the api message on my dashboard nither my Echo is listening

.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

PUSHER_APP_ID=123
PUSHER_APP_KEY=p123
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=s123
PUSHER_HOST='127.0.0.1'
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Echo

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
    encrypted: false,
});
```

my dashboard shows subscribed but the api message are not showing on the dashboard nither the Echo server is listening to the event

Comment: Does this help? Worked for me.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964481/2562428](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964481/2562428)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change env `PUSHER_PORT=443` to `PUSHER_PORT=6001`
2. Higher versions of `pusher-php 7.2` and `laravel-websockets 1.13` are incompatible. So, downgrade pusher to 7.0. You can use this to install pusher version 7.0 `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server:7.0 -W`
3. You may need to change env `PUSHER_SCHEME=https` to `PUSHER_SCHEME=http` for your local enviroment

Comment: thank you puher 7.0 is working perfectly fine.

Comment: i have spent hours on this even with a fresh Laravel installation but I keep getting this error
```Exception ErrorException thrown: Undefined property: Ratchet\Server\IoConnection::$app```

currently running on PHP 8.1

Comment: Can you share more details about your setup?