# Laravel web sockets(beyondcode) suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

One day I realized that my web sockets are not working in my production Apache server. So, I tried to debug there and found nothing wrong, queues are working, socket clients are connecting but not receiving anything on clients side.

How? - No Idea
Since When? - No Idea

So, I decided to test it all in my local environment as I did earlier before deployment.

I am using [laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) for web sockets implementation.

I am using below Vue.js code to debug my socket connection:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import Pusher from "pusher-js";
window.Pusher = Pusher;

const token = "44|yiPuLJM1DviFgX7Aq6cZPam86eyQMYoNssZQs2gl"
const tenant = "test"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'laravel_rdb',
    wsHost: '127.0.0.1',
    authEndpoint: 'http://localhost/myapp/public/broadcasting/auth',
    encrypted: false,
    forceTLS: false,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort:6001,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    auth : {
        headers : {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
            Accept: "application/json",
            'X-Tenant': tenant,
        }
    },
})

window.Echo.private(tenant + '.notifications.user.1')
    .listen('NotifyUser', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
})

window.Echo.connector.pusher.connection.bind('state_change', (state) => {
    console.log('Debug - Current connection state: ' + state.current);

    if (window.Echo.websocketsState !== '' && state.current === 'connected') {
        console.log("Status Update: " + state.current);
    } else if (window.Echo.websocketsState !== '' && state.current === 'failed') {
        window.Echo.reconnectInterval = window.setInterval(() => {
            var ifConnected = window.navigator.onLine;
            if (ifConnected) {
                clearInterval(window.Echo.reconnectInterval);
                console.log("Status Update 2: " + state.current);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }

    window.Echo.websocketsState = state.current;
});
```

Using this code, I can see that web socket is connecting successfully but console is not showing anything about my send messages.

I am using database queue to process socket messages and using `php artisan queue:work` I can see that my broadcast queues are being processed.

I tested with web sockets dashboard as well. I can see my channel as subscribed when I start my Vue.js code but when I try to send an event message to that channel from the dashboard it does nothing. No errors, no alerts, nothing.

I haven't done any changes to my web sockets code. The same code was working fine without any issues, but it suddenly stopped working and the most frustrating thing is that there are no errors at all.

Only possible error causing factor I am guessing is, compatibility issues with some dependent packages or Laravel framework itself as I update them regularly. It has been a long time since I have checked web sockets, so I am not really sure what might have caused the issue.

Comment: Does this help? Worked for me.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964481/2562428](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964481/2562428)

Answer (score 0):

The problem and the solution has been explained here: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/1041

The discussion here suggests to either downgrade the version of `pusher/pusher-php-server` to `7.0.2` or use the dev branch of `beyondcode/laravel-websockets` which has it fixed.