# Doesn't connect production websockets server with laravel

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-websockets

The problem is that when I enter the path https://my.domain.com/laravel-websockets and click connect, the server does not start up.

Stack is: Laravel 8 , Apache2 + Vanilla Js

I have this in my .env

```
PUSHER_APP_HOST="${APP_URL}"
PUSHER_APP_PORT=6001
PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=
PUSHER_APP_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_USE_TLS=true
PUSHER_APP_ENCRYPTED=true
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
```

wss://mydomain.com:6001/app/c0a9690c2088dc2dec86?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false**

I get this error
`WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.`
I need help please.

[image]

change host in my environment , change port , etc...

Comment: Does this help? Worked for me.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964481/2562428](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964481/2562428)