# Can't get Laravel-Websockets to work over SSL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I have a Laravel-Websockets server running on IIS 10.
When I run the website from `http://example.com/`, then Laravel-Echo sends the websocket ping using `ws://` and not `wss://` and everything is working - connection via websocket is successfull.

But when I run my website from `https`, then Laravel Echo forces `wss://` (And I guess I can't use `ws` while running `https`.

So I then added the following to the code:

1. The PEM certificate path in the `.env` file:

   LARAVEL_WEBSOCKET_LOCAL_CERT="D:\certs\cert.pem"

And in the `websocket.php` config file:

```
'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKET_LOCAL_CERT', null),
```

I also edited the `broadcasting.php` config file to use `https` and change some curl option as seen in the docs:

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => 'https',
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        ]
    ],
],
```

And lastly in the frontend I changed the Echo settings to use `wss` with `wss` port key:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your-pusher-key',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
});
```

But now whenever I try to connect to `wss` instead of `ws`, it says `(pending)` then `Finished` and it's `N/A` in the devtools.

And I can't debug because there are no errors that tell why the connection fails

And again, when I change the address back to `http://` and it tries to connect via `ws://`, it works and the connection is successful

So what can it be? Perhaps the `.pem` file is not right?

**Edit:**

I am using the same certificate used for the `https` connection - is it correct? Or I need a dedicated certificate specifically for the `wss` connection? (And then ask from the devops team to create one for me)?

The problem is, that I got the certificate as a `.pfx` file and I used OpenSSL to extract the`.p7b` file (#PKCS7 certificate) and convert it to a `.pem` file, and this is what I'm using for the PEM path.

But I'm not sure if it's working or whether it's the problem at all because I can't debug that.

The `.pem` file contents now looks like:

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
[..long string..]
-----END PKCS7-----
```

But the URLs are different - The client connects from `mysite-websockets.com` and the client is `mysite.com` (for example), and I am using the SSL certificate of `mysite-websockets.com` (so maybe cross-origin issue?)

Comment: Does this help? Worked for me.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964481/2562428](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964481/2562428)